# GridView CommandName = "INSERT" not working

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I am using GridView data bound control and trying to insert a record from the footer template, below is snapshot of my code:

[image]

The insert command doesn't seem to be working as expected. Insert button click does not do anything. However, if I have a delete button with CommandName="Delete" (with same markup), it works fine.

Does GridView not understand the "Insert" CommandName? Am I missing anything?

Thanks!

Comment: Is your table `Id` identity insert?

Comment: I would agree with @T.S. Identity fields typically are of autonumber type, so you should not try to force the value. Plus, INSERT new record is typically handled by ASP.NET FormView control. Best regards,

Comment: No its not an identity insert. I understand that GridView does not support insert operations, so does this mean the INSERT CommandName is not recognized by GridView (as above) or its just that AutoGenerateInsert button is not available for GridView?

Answer (score 0):

GridView in ASP.NET does not support insert operations.  Lots of people have added a footer row and a button to that row to do the insert. example: http://geekswithblogs.net/casualjim/archive/2005/08/29/51360.aspx

My personal preference is to have a detailsview linked to the gridview and do inserts through the detailsview.  It's not pretty but it works.  the footer row solution is much nicer.

Comment: Deepak, I'm not sure what you are asking above.

Comment: I understand now and see you have the footer.  you do need to implement the inserting event on the datasource and include a button in the footer that calls that (see the url I mentioned above for example).  I don't know of an autogenerateinsert option in gridview