# Where should I put my UpdatePanel

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, gridview

I have been tasked with updating an ASP web Application to Visual Studio 2015.  I have a Master page that looks like this:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="HorizontalMenu.master.cs" Inherits="HomiLog2015.HorizontalMenu" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/Header and Footer/Footer.ascx" TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="Footer" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/Header and Footer/Header.ascx" TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="Header" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/Menu.ascx" TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="Menu" %>
<link href="App_Themes/Rockies/BaseStyles.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>

<body id="Body1" runat="server">
<form runat="server" id="form1" method="post">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="scriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="True" EnablePageMethods="True" EnableScriptGlobalization="True" EnableScriptLocalization="True">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
    <table border="0">
        <tr>
            <td class="pcT" colspan="2">
                <uc1:Header runat="server" ID="Header1" />
            </td>
            <td class="pcTR"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="pcml"></td>
            <td class="MLMmc">
                <uc1:Menu runat="server" id="Menu1" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="pcL"></td>
            <td class="pcC">
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PageContent" runat="server"/>
            </td>
            <td class="pcR"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="pcBL"></td>
            <td class="pcB">
                <uc1:Footer runat="server" ID="Footer1" />
            </td>
            <td class="pcBR"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I Have an  ASP web page with a GridView and need to Edit, Delete, and Insert records.  I have gotten the edit and delete functions running but am having a problem with the Insert portion.

When I attempt to save the new record all of the data fields are empty. I know the C# code is reading the text values on the row because I have a dropdown and a checkbox on the rows that are getting their values, but it is the default values and not the ones I selected for the insert.

Pretty sure it is a post back problem since I have noticed I don't have an UpdatePanel on my web page.  I have tried to wrap the gridview within an UpdatePanel but when I do that I get the error stating GridView is not a known element. I have tried wrapping the gridview in a Div and then wrapping the div in the update panel. But then I get the Error div cannot be nested in the update panel.

So I think I need to include the update panel on the Master page but cannot get it to compile when I move it over there. I have tried putting the panel in various location on the Master Page. Can someone point me in the right direction on this?

I have been asked to provide more code here is the ASPX page that has the gridview

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/HorizontalMenu.Master" 
AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="EditMembers.aspx.cs" 
Inherits="HomiLog2015.EditMembers" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" 
TagPrefix="telerik" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="PageContent" 
runat="server">
<section id="searchHeader" class="Search">
    <p class="searchp">Members</p>
</section>
<section id="SearchArea" class="SearchBar">
    Search for:
    <br />
    <br />
    Last Name:
</section>
<section id="searchFooter" class="Search">
    <p>*</p>
</section>
<telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="RadAjaxManager1" runat="server">
</telerik:RadAjaxManager>
<telerik:RadAjaxLoadingPanel ID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1" runat="server" 
Skin="Default"></telerik:RadAjaxLoadingPanel>
<telerik:RadFormDecorator ID="RadFormDecorator1" runat="server" />
<section id="grid" class="Grid-Container">
    <p style="text-align: Left;">
        <asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="Server" Text="Add New Record" 
OnClick="btnAdd_Click" /></p>

    <asp:GridView ID="MembersGridView" runat="server" EnableViewState="true"
        DataKeyNames="UserId"
        AutoGenerateColumns="false"
        AutoGenerateEditButton="true"
        AutoGenerateDeleteButton="false"
        OnRowDataBound="MembersGridView_RowDataBound"
        OnRowEditing="MembersGridView_RowEditing"
        OnRowCancelingEdit="MembersGridView_RowCancelingEdit"
        OnRowUpdating="MembersGridView_RowUpdating"
        OnRowUpdated="MembersGridView_RowUpdated"
        OnRowDeleting="MembersGridView_RowDeleting"
        OnRowCommand="MembersGridView_RowCommand"
        OnSorting="MembersGridView_Sorting"
        AllowPaging="true"
        AllowSorting="true"
        EmptyDataText="No Data Has Been Entered"
        HorizontalAlign="Left"
        ShowFooter="false"
        OnPageIndexChanging="MembersGridView_PageIndexChanging" 
BackColor="White" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="Solid" 
BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Vertical">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="MembersDeleteButton"
                        CommandArgument='<%#Eval("username")%>'
                        OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want 
to delete this event?');"
                        OnCommand="DeleteMember" Text="Delete"
                        ImageUrl="../Images/Icon_delete.gif">
</asp:ImageButton>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Valid" ItemStyle-Width="10">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkActive" runat="server" Checked='<%# 
Eval("valid")%>' Enabled="false"></asp:CheckBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkActive" runat="server" Checked='<%# 
Eval("valid")%>'></asp:CheckBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkActive" runat="server" />
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="First Name" ItemStyle-
Width="100">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblFirstName" runat="server" Text='<%# 
Eval("firstname")%>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server" Text='<%# 
Eval("firstname")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" Text="Hello" 
runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Last Name" ItemStyle-Width="100">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblLastName" runat="server" Text='<%# 
Eval("Lastname")%>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtLastName" runat="server" Text='<%# 
Eval("Lastname")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtLastName" runat="server">
</asp:TextBox>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="User Name" ItemStyle-Width="100">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblUsertName" runat="server" Text='<%# 
Eval("username")%>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" runat="server" Text='<%# 
Eval("username")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" runat="server">
</asp:TextBox>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Role" ItemStyle-Width="100">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblRole" runat="server" Text='<%# 
Eval("role")%>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlRole" runat="server" 
DataTextField="Role1" DataValueField="RoleID"></asp:DropDownList>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlRole" runat="server" 
DataTextField="Role1" DataValueField="RoleID"></asp:DropDownList>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Email" ItemStyle-Width="100">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblEmail" runat="server" Text='<%# 
Eval("EmailAddress")%>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtemail" runat="server" Text='<%# 
Eval("EmailAddress")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnInsert" runat="Server" Text="Insert" 
CommandName="Insert" UseSubmitBehavior="False" />
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
        <PagerSettings Mode="Numeric"
            Position="Bottom"
            PageButtonCount="10" />

        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="Black" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />

        <PagerStyle BackColor="#999999"
            Height="30px"
            VerticalAlign="Bottom"
            HorizontalAlign="center" ForeColor="Black" />

        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#000099" Font-Bold="True" 
ForeColor="White" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#808080" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#383838" />

        <EmptyDataTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkActive" runat="server" Checked='<%# 
Eval("valid")%>' Enabled="false"></asp:CheckBox>
            <asp:Label ID="lblFirstName" runat="server" Text='<%# 
Eval("firstname")%>'></asp:Label>
            <asp:Label ID="lblLastName" runat="server" Text='<%# 
Eval("Lastname")%>'></asp:Label>
            <asp:Label ID="lblUsertName" runat="server" Text='<%# 
Eval("username")%>'></asp:Label>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlRole" runat="server" 
DataTextField="Role1" DataValueField="RoleID"></asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:Label ID="lblEmail" runat="server" Text='<%# 
Eval("EmailAddress")%>'></asp:Label>
        </EmptyDataTemplate>


    </asp:GridView>

</section>

</asp:Content>
```

I have tried putting the update panel in various locations on this page but it will not compile.

Comment: What do you mean by "update an app to to Visual Studio 2015"? That doesn't make any sense really. Visual Studio is an IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Master pages are for styling. You should not be touching them in this case.

Add the **MasterPageFile** attribute to the *Page* element in your .aspx markup file that contains your GridView.

```
 <%@ Page MasterPageFile="~/YOUR_MASTER_PAGE_FILE" ... %>
```

Note the id of the *asp:ContentPlaceHolder* in your Master page.

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PageContent" runat="server"/>
```

Wrap the content of your new .aspx page in a *asp:Content* element which has an attribute *asp:ContentPlaceHolderID* equal to the ID of the *asp:ContentPlaceHolder* element in your master page file.

```
<asp:Content ID="mainPlaceHolder" ContentPlaceHolderID="PageContent" runat="server">
```

[Here is an example for inserting records using a GridView](http://www.asphelps.com/GridView/How-to-insert-new-rows-in-GridView-in-Asp.Net.aspx)

Please post the relevant markup and back-end code for you GridView and insert logic. I can't offer any more assistance based on the information provided.

Comment: Thanks @withmetta I have posted the HTML from the aspx page the gridview is on.  Looks like the content area is setup as you explained.

Comment: What's the difference between btnAdd and btnInsert?

Comment: It also looks like you need to implement OnRowCreated https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.onrowcreated(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: The btnAdd changes the footer shows the FooterTemplate by setting its property IsVisible to true. Btn Insert is the code to call the stored procedure to enter the record in the database.  Both of those work as planned and a record does get entered into the database.  Just not the data I entered into the fields

Comment: [Follow this answer here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27880814/gridview-commandname-insert-not-working) Inserting is not handled by GridViews automatically. You're going to have to write your own logic.